# Continuing while loop after catching an InputMissMatchException, Java

Tags: java, while-loop, try-catch

I'm new in Java and have a problem after catching an exception. After catching an exception the program ends, but i want to continue the loop. The use of the program is that a user type in numbers between 1 and 10 through a scanner until the typed number is equal to the random number defined before.

```
public class GuessingGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Welcome!");

        int min = 1;
        int max = 1000;

        int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min) + 1) + min;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int firstDraw = 1;
        int maxDraw = 1000;

        try {

            while (firstDraw < maxDraw) {

                System.out.println("Please enter your guess: ");

                int guessingNumber = scanner.nextInt();

                if (guessingNumber < randomNumber) {
                    System.out.println("Too small!");
                } else if (guessingNumber > randomNumber) {
                    System.out.println("Too big!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("You win");
                }
                firstDraw++;
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Not a number - try again!");
        }
    }
}
```

I guess the problem is, where im going to place the try-catch block. I tried several possibilities but i dont get the right solution. If I just type in numbers, the program works and it ends until i guessed the right number. But if i use letters instead of numbers, it ends the program. I also saw some similiar problems asked before but i really don't get it

Thy for your help fellows :)

Comment: Have you tried moving the `try-catch-block` inside the `while-block` ?  Also see `Random.nextInt(1000)+1` for a more concise form of your random generation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> *"... After catching an exception the program ends, but i want to continue the loop. ..."*

Use the *[Scanner#next](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#next())*, and *[Integer#parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))*, methods.
And, place the *try-catch* within the *loop*.

Additionally, when the correct value is guessed, *break* the *loop*.

Note that the *parseInt* method throws a *NumberFormatException*, and not a *InputMismatchException*.

```java
while (firstDraw < maxDraw) {

    System.out.println("Please enter your guess: ");

    try {
        int guessingNumber = Integer.parseInt(scanner.next());

        if (guessingNumber < randomNumber) {
            System.out.println("Too small!");
        } else if (guessingNumber > randomNumber) {
            System.out.println("Too big!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You win");
            break;
        }
        firstDraw++;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println("Not a number - try again!");
    }
}
```

Output

```
Welcome!
Please enter your guess: 
abc
Not a number - try again!
Please enter your guess: 
123
Too small!
Please enter your guess: 
456
Too big!
Please enter your guess: 
241
You win
```

On a final note, you can utilize the *[RandomGenerator#nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/random/RandomGenerator.html#nextInt(int,int))* method, to specify a bounds.

```java
int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(min, max + 1);
```

Comment: thx, helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you want?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Welcome!");

    int min = 1;
    int max = 1000;

    int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * (max - min) + 1) + min;

    int firstDraw = 1;
    int maxDraw = 1000;


        while (firstDraw < maxDraw) {

            System.out.println("Please enter your guess: ");

            try {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                int guessingNumber = scanner.nextInt();

                if (guessingNumber < randomNumber) {
                    System.out.println("Too small!");
                } else if (guessingNumber > randomNumber) {
                    System.out.println("Too big!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("You win");
                    break;
                }
                firstDraw++;

            } catch (InputMismatchException e){
                System.out.println("Not a number - try again!");
            }

        }

}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: thx, i noticed that i also had to put the initiliazation of the scanner in the try catch block and while loop

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem:

1. the try-catch needs to be inside the while-loop and not the reverse.
2. the scanner.nextInt() needs a scanner.nextLine() just below it like so: [click to see code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvRhh.png).
3. you need a scanner.nextLine() inside the catch-statement: [click to see code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbNgR.png)